# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" using Jython

Tags: java, python, module, jython, callable

I have a python module, consisting of `import_ical.py` and `__init__.py` in my directory  . Calling this module from console works, when using:
    python -m .import_ical .import_ical.py

When I call the same module using Jython, I get:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
  at org.python.core.Py.TypeError(Py.java:263)
  at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:390)
  at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:496)
  at services.imports.CalendarImporter.importFromUrl(CalendarImporter.java:53)
  at services.imports.CalendarImporterTest.testMultipleEventsImport(CalendarImporterTest.java:21)
  [...]
```

**CalendarImporter.importFromUrl()** does the following:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('<dir>')");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')");
interpreter.exec("import import_ical");
PyObject importIcalPy = interpreter.get("import_ical");
PyObject pythonResult = importIcalPy.__call__(<parameters go here>);
```

When I execute my JUnit test (`CalendarImporterTest`) that executes this Jython code, a class file is generated in my module directory, named **import_ical$py.class**. It contains the following lines (amongst others):

```
@Filename("<dir>/import_ical.py")
public class import_ical$py extends PyFunctionTable implements PyRunnable {
  [....]
  static final PyCode __call__$20;
  [....]

  public PyObject __call__$20(PyFrame var1, ThreadState var2) {
    var1.setline(243);
    PyObject var3 = var1.getglobal("import_ical").__call__(var2, var1.getlocal(0), var1.getlocal(1), var1.getlocal(2));
    var1.f_lasti = -1;
    return var3;
  }
}
```

**Debugging** to the last line of my `CalendarImporter` Java code shown above gives me the following variables states:

```
interpreter = {PythonInterpreter}
  [...]
  globals = {PyStringMap}
    table
      [...]
      1 = {ConcurrentHashMap$MapEntry} "import_ical" -> "<module 'import_ical' from '<dir>/import_ical$py.class'>"
      [...]
    [...]
  [...]
importIcalPy = {PyModule}
  [...]
  __dict__ = {PyStringMap}
    table
      [...]
      19 = {ConcurrentHashMap$MapEntry} "import_ical" -> "<function import_ical at 0xc>"
      [...]
      32 = {ConcurrentHashMap$MapEntry} "__call__" -> "<function __call__ at 0x13>"
      [...]
    [...]
  [...]
```

As a python newbie, I cannot detect anything that would arouse my scepticism with regards to the generated class file of the module and even the variables' state shown above seems to tell me that there is a proper function `__call__` within in my python module `importIcalPy`.

Note: I had already added the function `__call__` to my python module to make the module by "callable" from Jython and catch this error - obviously without success.

So can anyone please tell me: **why do I get that "not callable" error? And what can I do to prevent it?** Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you!

[Comment: I have intensely searched for a solution both, in Stackoverflow and using a big search engine, but all search results lead me to another problem where a python module could not call another python module.]

Comment: "Calling this module from console works, when using: python -m .import_ical .import_ical.py" - that's not calling the module. Modules aren't callable. If you were expecting module objects to implement `__call__` equivalent to `python -m thatmodule`, no, that's not how modules work.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for clarification. As I noted, I manually added `__call__` to make the module callable by Java, whereas it had already been executing fine using `python -m` before. My unprecise expression "calling this module" is resulting from the error message (see question header). Anyway, this does not help me solving this problem, does it?

Comment: Putting a `__call__` function in a module won't make it callable. It would make the Python attribute access `import_ical.__call__` succeed, but the Java-side `__call__` method is a different method that will ignore your function. (The Python side would also ignore your `__call__` function if you tried something like `import_ical()`.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks again! Interesting - I didn't see that these are different `__call__` functions. So, coming back to the error Message: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable": what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Module objects aren't callable. You're trying to call a module object. It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, and thanks to the hints of user2357112, I've found a fix. Replace the content of CalendarImporter.importFromUrl() shown above with the following code:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('<dir>')");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')");
interpreter.exec("import import_ical");
// set variables if necessary in script:
// interpreter.set("__file__", <myFile>);
// set system argument variables (one append per variable):
interpreter.exec("sys.argv.append('".concat("<myVar>").concat("')"));
interpreter.execfile("<fileWithQualifiedPath>");
PyObject importIcalPy = interpreter.get("import_ical");
PyObject pythonResult = importIcalPy.__call__(new PyString("<myScriptArgument>"));
```

Hope, it will help someone.